# Choosing the correct tense

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I need to know whether to choose the past tense or the present tense. The sentence is talking about my
grandfather when he was in the primary stage so, we needed to use the past tense (in my opinion as a beginner), but I asked my native teacher and told me that the correct answer is the first one!
Can you help me solve this problem?

Choose the correct answer:

> Little.........................to primary school.
>
> 1. does my grandfather go
> 2. did my grandfather go

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Unfortunately, neither of the options are correct. Neither sentence is idiomatic. In general terms, you are correct - actions in the past are described in the past tense.

Comment: I am sure your grandfather does not go to (or stay away from) school, so you would need the past tense (unless there is a complicated narrative which is not disclosed).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I guess you're not meaning "My grandfather seldom goes to school", but maybe "My grandfather seldom went to primary school when he was young"?

Answer (score 1):

It should certainly be past tense for this past event.

This is a strange question.  The tense is a very basic part of English, but the sentence uses some advanced grammar, such as the subject-verb inversion triggered by the negative adverb.

The use of "little" is not correct.  It can be used as an adverb, but it means "not much". It doesn't mean "not often".  So there is a fixed expression "Little did he know that ..." But it is odd to say "Little did my grandfather go to school."  The correct adverb should be "seldom" or "rarely" (etc).

So this question is a strange mix of elementary grammar, advanced grammar, and incorrect English.

So "Seldom did my grandfather go to school". Or without the overly formal inversion, "My grandfather seldom went to school".